# Merge non-standard PDFs with pyPdf

Tags: python, pdf, python-2.6, pypdf

I would like to merge a couple of PDF files into a single PDF document. As it turns out, the input files are not fully standard-compliant. The EOF marker is followed by some additional information:

```
>>
startxref
1994481
%%EOF

%%PPIRoute: 4
```

Obviously, this results in pyPdf [giving me an exception](https://github.com/mfenniak/pyPdf/blob/trunk/pyPdf/pdf.py#L707):

```
pyPdf.utils.PdfReadError: EOF marker not found
```

Now the question is: What should I do? I could probably open each file, strip the last two lines and save it before throwing them into pyPdf. However, I don't like that idea very much. Maybe there is a better option out there?

Comment: Derive a subclass of `PdfFileReader` that does what you want in its `read()` method. Alternatively, create your own smart `stream` object and pass that to the existing `read()` method.

Comment: Is changing `pdf.py` an option? It looks like it would be easy to modify it handle the problem (assuming it's OK to delete/ignore the additional information in the file(s)).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest changing the beginning of the`read()`method of the`PdfFileReader`class in the pdf.py script from:

```
    def read(self, stream):
        # start at the end:
        stream.seek(-1, 2)
        line = ''
        while not line:
            line = self.readNextEndLine(stream)
        if line[:5] != "%%EOF":
            raise utils.PdfReadError, "EOF marker not found"

    ... etc
```

to:

```
    def read(self, stream):
        # start at the end:
        stream.seek(-1, 2)
        line = ''
        # read stream backwards while watching for end-of-file marker
        while line[:5] != "%%EOF":
            line = self.readNextEndLine(stream)

    ... etc
```

In my opinion the original code is not really doing what is implied by section 3.4.4, “File Trailer” (page 628) in Adobe's [PDF 1.3 Reference](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference13.pdf) document where it says (italics mine):

> Acrobat viewers require *only* that the %%EOF marker appear somewhere
>   within the last 1024 bytes of the file.

In other words, it's OK for there to be other stuff before the physical end of the file after the`"%%EOF"` marker. The changes I propose attempt to accommodate this and make it ignore anything else that may have been tacked onto the end of the file after the marker rather than raising an exception (however it doesn't require the`"%%EOF"`to be in the last 1K bytes as the spec says, although a check for that could be added). This also means that the files you're trying to merge may, in fact, conform to the spec.

**Update:**

Here's a version that also requires the`"%%EOF"`marker to be within the last 1024 bytes:

```
def read(self, stream):
    # start at the end
    stream.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    last1K = stream.tell() - 1024 + 1 # offset of last 1024 bytes of stream

    # read stream backwards while watching for end-of-file marker
    line = ''
    while line[:5] != "%%EOF":
        line = self.readNextEndLine(stream)
        if stream.tell() < last1K:
            raise utils.PdfReadError, "EOF marker not found"

    ... etc
```

Comment: cyroxx: Did you ever try what's in my answer?

Comment: Not yet, since it is a small project that I haven't looked into for a while. Thank you so far for your answer, I will comment/vote as soon as I tried your suggested solution.

Comment: When line is empty '' it says ... ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '%%EOF' . Earlier code wont not enter the loop . Any thoughts martineau ?